# I2C devices - How to physically connect multiple devices

Tags: i2c

I have a one of these https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/adafruit-veml6075-uva-uvb-and-uv-index-sensor-breakout and one of these https://taaralabs.eu/1-wire-shield-for-wemos-d1/ I would like to connect to my RPi3.

The first product comes with some pins as below

[image]

which I assume is to allow me to stack one on top of another.  However what if I want to have more such i2c devices attached?  The below would seem to only support one on top and one below the black plastic blocks. Do I just need to get more of these pins and put them on a breadboard or is there a better way?  Once I've finished prototyping I intend to solder rather than have a breadboard.

Comment: How far apart are you planning to mount them? How do you plan to individually access them? From what I have read the I2C address cannot be changed on these devices, so you can't have multiple on the same bus.

Comment: The pins are for cables, not to stack the boards. You break off four pins and solder those. Then you have cables to the Pi GPIO.

Comment: Thanks @Tomas By. I can see how that would allow me to connect the first board back to the RPi, but how should I best connect that first I2C board to other ones?

Comment: I don't know about best but if you have multiple I2C devices with different addresses then that should be fine I think (ie all connected to the same SDA/SCL pins).

Comment: Thanks.  I think I'm being really dim here, but if those pins connect via jumper cables back to the RPi (i.e. SDA/SCL on the board back to relevant GPIO pins) how do I go from the SDA/SCL pin on the I2C device to the next I2C device?  Must I go via a breadboard?

Comment: There are some options, like [one of these](https://www.ebay.com/itm/GPIO-Expansion-Board-Raspberry-Pi-Shield-for-Raspberry-PI-2-3-B-B-With-Screws-R/173526236602?hash=item2866f83dba:g:jzoAAOSwYelbliDw&frcectupt=true) if you have lots of things, or you could just make y-cables, by soldering or using screw terminals. Breadboard is not high on the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't connect them in parallel as they use the same fixed I2C address (0x10).  Every device on an I2C bus must have a unique address.

You have a number of options.

1. use an I2C multiplexor between the devices and the bus.  It acts as a gatekeeper allowing multiple devices with the same address to be used on the bus.  E.g. the TCA9548A.
2. use a bit banged I2C bus for one device and use the hardware I2C bus for another.  There is Linux driver support for software I2C buses on the Pi.  See `/boot/overlays/README` for details.

Comment: OK thanks.  So what if i only wanted to use one of those sensors but also have https://taaralabs.eu/1-wire-shield-for-wemos-d1/ which has a different address?  I'm primarily looking ot understand the physical connection requirements at the moment. I know that's probably a bit basic but want to understand how to wire them together neatly

Comment: Could you edit your question in the light of what you now plan to do?  However I doubt there is a best way.  I suggest you include whether you plan a temporary or permanent installation.

Comment: thanks @joan, I have improve my question i hope

Answer (score 4):

To connect multiple physical devices to the i2c bus, I connect the GND, Vcc, SDA and SCL pins from the Pi to the first i2c device, and then those to the next one etc.
Daisy chaining (or wiring in parallel).
I don't have a good answer for the physical wiring - essentially you want to 'tap' a 4-wire ribbon for each device.
As above, the devices must have different bus addresses.